# Is momentum conserved in this system?

Tags: momentum

We have a mass initially at rest on a ramp/wedge of arbitrary shape (i.e., not necessarily a triangle). There is no friction anywhere (including no friction between wedge and table).

(1) Am I correct in believing that we cannot say $$m_{wedge}v_{wedge}+m_{obj}v_{obj}=0$$ when the object gets to the bottom of the wedge, as there is an outside force (gravity)?

(2) Assuming I am correct there, then is there anything we can say about $$m_{wedge}v_{wedge}+m_{obj}v_{obj}?$$

- Does it depend on both the shape of the wedge and initial height of the object, or on the time before the object reaches the bottom of the wedge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentum is conserved because of the third law of Newton, that says that in an isolated system the sum of all forces at an instant is 0.

Your system is not isolated: there is gravity, reaction forces of the table and the floor... so no, your local momentum is not conserved.

That is easy to see, momentum is a vector, just look at the vertical componen of your momentum: first it is 0, then it goes down, and then it is 0 again, when the ball gets to the bottom.

That said, there is some more in your question: since you are dismissing any kind of friction,  and assuming that the table where the wedge lays is perfectly horizontal, the all external forces are perfectly vertical, so the sum of the horizontal component of all the forces is 0. Thus, in this (unphysical) scenario the horizontal component of the total momentum is conserved. When the ball slides to the right the wedge will slide to the left with opposte momentum.

Answer (score 0):

See velocity is a vector and so is momentum. Considering the field of gravity to be uniform we can say that it acts in the dircetion of the negative y axis, but since there is no force along the y axis direction momentum very well stays conserved, and since there is no dissipation of the initial gravitational potential energy it also stays conserved.